# non- Static method Reference error

Tags: java, jdbc

Ok so in my mail class im calling

```js
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable () {
    getLogger().info("Loading configs...");
        Hud.startHud();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisable () {

    }
}
```

and it give me 
non-static method cannot be referenced from static context

```js
public class Hud extends JavaPlugin {
    public void startHud () {
        ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
        Scoreboard board = manager.getNewScoreboard();
        Team team = board.registerNewTeam("teamname");
        Objective objective = board.registerNewObjective("test", "dummy");
        Score score = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GREEN + "Kills:"); //Get a fake offline player
        score.setScore(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn Java carefully. It will remove such questions. Your method `startHud` in `Hud` class is instance method. While you try to call method of class `Hud.startHud()`. You should add `static` keyword between `public` and `void` in `startHud` method definition.

Answer (score 0):

Make startHud() a static method. else call it like `new Hud().startHud();`